# Cannot link with boost::locale -- strange behavior in objdump

Tags: c++, boost, linker

I'm trying to make a static library of boost::locale and see a strange behavior: several functions occur in objdump both as defined and as declared-not-defined (here is one of them):

```
$ objdump -t libboost_locale.a | grep posix14create_convert
00000000000000a3 g     F .text  0000000000000335 _ZN5boost6locale10impl_posix14create_convertERKSt6localeNS_10shared_ptrIP15__locale_structEEj
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 _ZN5boost6locale10impl_posix14create_convertERKSt6localeNS_10shared_ptrIP15__locale_structEEj
```

When I link with this file, I get an «undefined reference to» error. Although, many others boost functions work as intended.

Everything is built by a rather complicated build system used in our company, so unfortunately I cannot show you the build command.

What could be the reason of such a weird behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> several functions occur in objdump both as defined and as declared-not-defined

There is nothing strange about that: the archive library contains a collection of object (`.o`) files. One of these files defines the function. Other object files reference but not define it. You can see which reference is which with:

```
nm -A libboost_locale.a | grep posix14create_convert
```

> When I link with this file, I get an «undefined reference to» error.

This is most likely because you've put `libbost_locale` in the wrong place on the link line. You *must* put it *after* the object file which references the function. A very good explanation of how the linker works with archive libraries can be found [here](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/07/09/library-order-in-static-linking). Here is an older (but shorter) [explanation](http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.html).